# Reshape multivariable data with two rows as headers (wide to long)

Tags: r, tidyr

I have an Excel sheet formatted like the following:

```
             2015    2015    2016    2016    2017    2017
Name         Height  Weight  Height  Weight  Height  Weight  
Alice        12      34      56      78      90      12      
Bob          55      55      55      55      55      55     
...
```

My goal is to produce a tidy data frame like:

```
Name    Year    Height    Weight
Alice   2015    12        34
Alice   2016    56        78
Alice   2017    90        12
Bob     2015    55        55
Bob     2016    55        55
Bob     2017    55        55
...
```

I can see how one might use `read_excel` and then `gather` from the `tidyverse` to create a data frame if the year row didn't exist, but I don't understand how to do this with two header rows. The main point where I'm stuck is that obviously a column can only have one name, but it seems like I want to at least temporarily have two names for each column. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: @NelsonGon I don't think it's a dupe of that since the issue is really the multi-row column names in the Excel sheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a reasonably common problem (people actually use excel workbooks like that) but one that involves several steps to resolve in R. Here's one way to do it where I assume your dataframe is called `dat`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr) # for the two-way pipe %<>%

# Start by renaming your columns to include both the year and variable
# The use of '-' to separate the parts is for convenience in the regex below
names(dat)[2:ncol(dat)] <- paste(dat[1, 2:ncol(dat)],
                                 names(dat)[2:ncol(dat)],
                                 sep = "-")
names(dat)[1] <- "Name"
names(dat) <- sub("__\\d+", "", names(dat))

# Drop the now useless first row
dat <- dat[2:nrow(dat), ]

# Transform the data
dat %<>%
  gather(key = var, value = val, -Name) %>%
  mutate(Year = sub("^.*?-", "", var),
         var = sub("-\\d+$", "", var)) %>%
  spread(key = var, value = as.numeric(val))
```

The piped sequence that transforms the data works like this: First, your intuition was right in that we need to use `gather` to transform from wide to long. Second, we create our "Year" variable and get rid of those numbers from the temporary "var" variable. Finally, we have to use `spread` separate the Height and Weight variables. Since the second header row in the original data was text, we'll also transform those values into numeric in that step.

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky but common in getting data out of Excel files. I pasted your data into an xlsx file and read in with `readxl::read_excel`, but for the sake of reproducibility, I'm also pasting the `dput` output here. I set `col_names = F` so it would just have dummy column names, giving me each of those two header levels in rows, as shown below:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# df <- readxl::read_excel("multicols.xlsx", col_names = F)
df <- structure(list(...1 = c(NA, "Name", "Alice", "Bob"), ...2 = c("2015", 
                                                              "Height", "12", "55"), ...3 = c("2015", "Weight", "34", "55"), 
               ...4 = c("2016", "Height", "56", "55"), ...5 = c("2016", 
                                                                "Weight", "78", "55"), ...6 = c("2017", "Height", "90", "55"
                                                                ), ...7 = c("2017", "Weight", "12", "55")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                          -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>   ...1  ...2   ...3   ...4   ...5   ...6   ...7  
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 <NA>  2015   2015   2016   2016   2017   2017  
#> 2 Name  Height Weight Height Weight Height Weight
#> 3 Alice 12     34     56     78     90     12    
#> 4 Bob   55     55     55     55     55     55
```

The years are in the first row and the measures are in the second, so I pull each of those out:

```r
(yrs <- df[1,])
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   ...1  ...2  ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 <NA>  2015  2015  2016  2016  2017  2017
(cols <- df[2,])
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   ...1  ...2   ...3   ...4   ...5   ...6   ...7  
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 Name  Height Weight Height Weight Height Weight
```

Then I paste those two together to get a vector of decent column names:

```r
clean_names <- stringr::str_remove(paste(cols, yrs, sep = "_"), "_NA")
clean_names
#> [1] "Name"        "Height_2015" "Weight_2015" "Height_2016" "Weight_2016"
#> [6] "Height_2017" "Weight_2017"
```

Now I can remove those two rows and set proper names:

```r
df %>%
  slice(-1:-2) %>%
  setNames(clean_names)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#>   Name  Height_2015 Weight_2015 Height_2016 Weight_2016 Height_2017
#>   <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
#> 1 Alice 12          34          56          78          90         
#> 2 Bob   55          55          55          55          55         
#> # … with 1 more variable: Weight_2017 <chr>
```

Lastly, reshape the data into a long shape, separate the key into the measure (height or weight) and year, then spread back into a wide shape.

```r
df %>%
  slice(-1:-2) %>%
  setNames(clean_names) %>%
  gather(key, value, -Name) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("measure", "year")) %>%
  spread(key = measure, value)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   Name  year  Height Weight
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 Alice 2015  12     34    
#> 2 Alice 2016  56     78    
#> 3 Alice 2017  90     12    
#> 4 Bob   2015  55     55    
#> 5 Bob   2016  55     55    
#> 6 Bob   2017  55     55
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called melting or reshaping your data from wide format to long format.

Suppose your data is stored in `dt`. Here's a `data.table` approach (which has nicer syntax than tidyverse):

```
library(data.table)
dt2 <- data.table(melt(dt, id.vars = "Name", variable.name = "Measurement", value.name = "Value"), year = rep(rep(2015:2017, each = 2), times = 2))
```

Output:

```
> dt2
     Name Measurement Value year
 1: Alice      Height    12 2015
 2:   Bob      Height    55 2015
 3: Alice      Weight    34 2016
 4:   Bob      Weight    55 2016
 5: Alice      Height    56 2017
 6:   Bob      Height    55 2017
 7: Alice      Weight    78 2015
 8:   Bob      Weight    55 2015
 9: Alice      Height    90 2016
10:   Bob      Height    55 2016
11: Alice      Weight    12 2017
12:   Bob      Weight    55 2017
```

You will notice that I have `Weight` and `Height` measurements in the same column. I recommend this instead of having a separate column for each variable because it is compatible with `group by` syntax.

The thing that is curious about your data is that you have two rows as headers. This means you will have to adjust the `year = ...` argument in my answer depending on your data.

In general, to create your `year` column, you need:

```
year = rep(rep(`insert year start`:`insert year end`),
           times = dt$Name %>% unique %>% length))
```